# Collection mutated while being enumerated crash in a switch case

Tags: ios, objective-c, collections, nsmutabledictionary

I'm using the library SRWebSocket and I have the following crash:
There seems to be no loop except the main SRWebSocket loop calling handleMessage:

```
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <_NSFaultingMutableSet: 0x14f60ced0> was mutated while being enumerated.

Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x181e0ae38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18146ff80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181e0a86c -[NSException name]
3  Appname                         0x1002507b0 -[WebSocketClient notification:] (WebSocketClient.m:534)
4  Appname                         0x10024fa68 -[WebSocketClient webSocket:didReceiveMessage:] (WebSocketClient.m:223)
5  Appname                         0x10017c260 __30-[SRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke (SRWebSocket.m:741)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1818554bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18185547c _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18185ab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181dc0dd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x181dbec40 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x181ce8d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x1835d0088 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKit                          0x186fbdf70 UIApplicationMain
14 Appname                         0x1003201e4 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1818868b8 (Missing)
```

first call in SRWebSocket:

```
- (void)_handleMessage:(id)message
{
    SRFastLog(@"Received message");
    [self _performDelegateBlock:^{
        [self.delegate webSocket:self didReceiveMessage:message];
    }];
}
```

- delegate class WebSocketClient -

First function call:

```
- (void)webSocket:(SRWebSocket *)webSocket didReceiveMessage:(id)message
{

  NSDictionary *dict = [message objectFromJSONString];
  int code = [[dict objectForKey:@"msgCode"] intValue];
  MessageType messageType = [[dict objectForKey:@"msgType"] intValue];

  if (self.loginBlock != nil && _autoLogining == NO) {

    [self feedbackLoginblock:dict];

    [self sendToken];
  }else{
    switch (messageType) {
      case MessageTypeReply:
      {
        NSString *matchIdentify = [dict objectForKey:@"msgId"];
        [self checkWaitingBlockQueue:matchIdentify code:code message:dict];
      }
        break;
      case MessageTypeReceiveMessage:{
        [self parseReadMessageFeedback:dict];
        NSInteger receiveInt = self.receiveNumber.intValue;
        receiveInt ++;
        self.receiveNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:receiveInt];
      }
        break;
      case MessageTypeAddGroup:{
        [self addMemberToGroup:dict];
      }
        break;
      case MessageTypeDeleteGroup:{
        [self deleteMemberFromGroup:dict];
      }
        break;
      case MessageTypeNotifyMsgType:{
        NSDictionary *content = [dict objectForKey:@"datacontent"];
        [self notification:content]; <<< LINE 223
      }
   }
}
```

Second call:

```
- (void)sendMessage:(Message *)message resultBlock:(MessageReplyBlock )block
{

  MessageBlock *messageBlock = [self createMessageBlock:block];
  [_waitingBlockQueue addObject:messageBlock];

  NSNumber *push;
  if(message.belongToSession.withSomebody) {

    push = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
  }else{
    push = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

  }
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               messageBlock.matchMessageID, @"matchID",
                               message.messageType, @"msgType",
                               message.sourceType, @"msgSourceT",
                               message.textContent, @"msgTextContent",
                               _currentUser.contactID, @"from",
                               push, @"push",
                               nil];
  MessageType messageType = [message.messageType integerValue];
  MessageSourceType sourceType = [message.sourceType integerValue];
  NSNumber *toContactID = message.toUser.contactID;
  if (toContactID == nil) {
    return;
  }

  if ([message.whisperType isEqualToNumber:@1]) {
    [dict setObject:@1 forKey:@"option"];
    [dict setObject:message.whisperTimeCount forKey:@"msgTimer"];
  }

  switch (messageType) {
    case MessageTypeImage:
    {
      [dict setObject:message.bigImagePath forKey:@"msgBigsrc"];
      [dict setObject:message.smallImagePath forKey:@"msgSmallsrc"]; <<< LINE 534
    }
      break;
    case MessageTypeOfflineAudio:
    {
      [dict setObject:message.webSourcePath forKey:@"msgUrl"];
      [dict setObject:message.voiceTime forKey:@"msgVoiceTime"];

    }
      break;
    case MessageTypeMap:
    {
      NSString *latitude = [message.latitude stringValue];
      NSString *longitude = [message.longitude stringValue];

      if (latitude.length > 0 && longitude.length > 0) {
        [dict setObject:latitude forKey:@"lat"];
        [dict setObject:longitude forKey:@"lng"];
      }
    }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  switch (sourceType) {
    case MessageSourceTypeP2p:
    {
      [dict setObject:toContactID forKey:@"to"];
    }
      break;
    case MessageSourceTypeGroup:
    {
      [dict setObject:toContactID forKey:@"gid"];
    }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];

  if(isConnected)
    [_webSocket send:data];
  else
    [self reconnect];
}
```

**Update with notification: method**

```
- (void)notification:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
  [[NotificationManager sharedManager] reloadRequestsCount];
  [[NotificationManager sharedManager] reloadNotificationCount];

  if (dict != nil) {

    NotificationType type = [[dict objectForKey:@"notificationType"] intValue];
    NSNumber *contactID = [dict objectForKey:@"notificationCreatorId"];
    if ([contactID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
      contactID = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[contactID longLongValue]];
    }

    [[SettingManager sharedSettingManager] playSoundWhenMessageReceived:contactID];

    switch (type) {
      case NotificationTypeAddFriend:
      case NotificationTypeAcceptFriend:
      {
        Friend *myFriend = [FetchReq fetchFriendWithFriendID:contactID ownerUserID:_contactID];

        if (myFriend == nil){
          if(type == NotificationTypeAcceptFriend) {
            NSNumber *notificationId = [dict objectForKey:@"notificationId"];
            [FetchReq notificationWithNotificationID:notificationId];
          }
        }else{
          myFriend.sendingRequest = @NO;
          myFriend.friend.sendingRequest = @NO;

          [APPDELEGATE saveContext];
        }
      }
        break;
      case NotificationTypeDeleteFriend:
      {
        User *user = [FetchReq fetchUserWithUserID:contactID];
        UserEntity *entity = [[UserEntity alloc] initWithUser:user];
        entity.user = user;
        [entity removeWithRelated];
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        NSNumber *notificationId = [dict objectForKey:@"notificationId"];
        [FetchReq notificationWithNotificationID:notificationId];
      }
        break;
    }
  }

  [APPDELEGATE saveContext];
}
```

Comment: The crash stack trace tells you the mutation happened in `notification:`, so why not post that method?

Comment: where is your default case of your switch statement???

Comment: default case exists but I stripped the rest of the switch case for better visibility.

Comment: The crash stack trace tells me the mutation happened in notification but the crash stack also tells me that the function concerned by the crash is the line 534 in the last function. I ll copy paste the notification: function too, maybe the problem is there. Thank you Avi